# Find area of this circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Given the circle O with perpendicular diameters and a chord, find the area of the circle if $EF = 8"$ and $DE = 20"$ inches.
[image: Nothing fishy :)]

Comment: EF > DE??????????????

Comment: Oh sorry. It's suppose to be DE = 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Draw the line segment $BE$ and use the fact that $\triangle ODF$ and $\triangle EDB$ are similar.

Comment: I finally figured out why that they are similar. But what I would appreciate is if you tell me how you went about noticing that the DEB is a right angle. Theorem? Experience?

Comment: @cavern101: It is a basic theorem often called [Thales' Theorem.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Thales+theorem&rlz=1CALEAE_enCA662CA662&oq=Thales+theorem&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.11539j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  The angle subtended by any diameter is a right-angle. The proof is not hard. Join $BE$, join $E$ to the center, and do some angle chasing.  I assume that from the similarity you can easily finish (it is one line). But if finishing causes difficulty, I can write it out.

Comment: Its fine. I understood it. I just want to see your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

As Andre said in his answer, $\Delta ODF$ ~ $\Delta EDB$.  Using the fact that similar triangle's corresponding sides are in proportion we can set up a proportion.  The eqaution is: $$\frac {DF}{DO}=\frac {DB}{DE}$$ We can assign the variable $x$ to $DO$ and we know that $DB=2x$ because $DB$ is a diameter and $DO$ is a radius. Now. it's as simple as substituting 12 for $DF$, $x$ for $DO$, $2x$ for $DB$ and 20 for $DE$ in the original proportion.  We get: $$\frac {12}{x}=\frac{2x}{20} \\ 2x^2=240 \\ x=\sqrt{120}$$ We now have the length of the radius, so we can use that in the formula for the area of a circle, $A=\pi r^2$, to find that the area is equal to $120\pi"$ or about 376.99". If you would like to, you can check the length of the radius using trigonometry, specifically the Law of Cosines.